# Angular2 ng2-auto-complete display and selection issues

Tags: javascript, html, angular, autocomplete

I have implemented the Angular 2 ngui-auto-complete component by following this [component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngui/auto-complete). And related to this i found [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExzNSh?p=preview). But the issue I'm facing is, on my auto-complete there multiple dependencies. So for that on selection I want id but I am not getting on selection id.

And one more facing issue is my source is in the form of an object with id as one of the fields. And by following the implementation example of the component, the id is displayed in parenthesis in the dropdown. Is there a way to not display the id in the dropdown?

Here is my HTML code for the auto-complete component:

```
<input  class="text-uppercase form-control" ngui-auto-complete [(ngModel)]="shipper.cust_name" [source]="shipperNameSource.bind(this)" value-property-name=null  value-formatter="cust_name" min-chars="1" (change)="updateShipperDetails()"/>
```

My component

```
shipperNameSource = (keyword: any): Observable<any[]> => {
    let url: string = 
      'api/getCustomers?selected='+keyword
    if (keyword) {
      return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => {
            let json = res.json();
            this.customer.id = json.id;
          return json;
        })
    } else {
      return Observable.of([]);
    }
}
```

This is what I get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your data. It is showing undefined means your data exist but there is something wrong with your mapping with auto-complete. Trying to log api response and check in which node you are getting actual data and map accordingly.

Comment: this error i resolved it but can suggest me how to remove id from listing and how to pass selected id in to another function I am totally stuck

Comment: Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Without seeing the api response. I can't help you with it. Log your api response by Console.log(res);